# In Rails, how can I pass a parameter to the `capture` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper, erb

In a Rails helper, you can `capture` the output of an ERB block using the `capture` method. However, what if the ERB block requires a parameter? How can I use `capture` in this case?

For a made-up example:

```
<% my_helper(:parameter, models) do |model| %>
  <%= model.eye_color %>
<% end %>
```

In the `my_helper` method, I want to surround the output of each iteration of the block with `<span class='color'>...</span>`.

I know I can capture the output of the ERB block and store it in a variable with `html = capture(&block)`, but I don't know how to pass the necessary `model` parameter to that block!

Comment: Can you not pass them into the call to `capture`? The docs show that it splats arguments, so I would assume they get passed to the block. E.g: `html = capture(:foo, :bar, &block)`

Comment: @coreyward Psst. Make that an answer to earn 25 points. :)

Comment: Wasn't sure if it was a hit. Done deal. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you not pass them into the call to capture? The docs show that it splats arguments, so I would assume they get passed to the block. E.g:

```
html = capture(:foo, :bar, &block)
```